# C# how can I pass a (filtered) file list to WebDav.Client and upload all files on that list? Right now I can only put individual files

Tags: c#, webdav

I am creating a webdav.client c# app that will scan selected directory for specific file types. Then take the list of found files and feed them to WebDav client to upload. Right now I can only upload single files.

```
public async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal;
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath).Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(file, @"^.+\.(txt|jpg|png)$"));
            {
                var clientParams = new WebDavClientParams { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myserver.com"), Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password") };
                using (var client = new WebDavClient(clientParams))
                {
                    await client.Mkcol(textBox2.Text+textBox1.Text); // create a directory
                    await client.PutFile("test.text", File.OpenRead("text.text")); // upload a resource
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through this files list and upload each file:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath).Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(file, @ "^.+\.(txt|jpg|png)$"));
foreach(var file in files) {
  var clientParams = new WebDavClientParams {
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myserver.com"), Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
  };
  using(var client = new WebDavClient(clientParams)) {
    await client.Mkcol(textBox2.Text + textBox1.Text); // create a directory
    await client.PutFile(file, File.OpenRead(file)); // upload a resource
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I tried your recommendation but for some reason nothing happens at all when I invoke the method,in other words the folder is not created or files uploaded. I don't even get an error message?